# Ubuntu 23.04 crashing with no log (Null characters in auth.log)

Tags: crash, 23.04

I recently updated from 22.04.2 LTS to 23.04 due to an app bug being fixed on a version that didn't support 22.04. Unfortunately, since upgrading I have had two crashes since updating that resulted in a system hang and required a hard reboot. `/var/log/syslog` stopped prior to the crash in both instances and `/var/log/kern.log` stops 3+ hours prior to syslog in both instances. In one instance, `/var/log/auth.log` ends with a line of null characters (@^@^@^@^), but the other crash did not result in a line of null characters. In both instances, `journalctl` ends within a few minutes of the other logs. None of the logs have anything out of the ordinary prior to the crash (just failed ssh attempts and timeserver updates).

Is there anywhere else I can look to find what is crashing? I checked every log file in `/var/log/` to no avail. The device simply just becomes unreachable and the power button needs to be held to force a reboot once it crashes.

Comment: I upgrade to 22.10 then 23.04. I did not do a reinstall, but if I can't figure this out that is my next step.

Comment: On your *hard reboot* are you ensuring all data in *buffers* (in RAM) gets written to disk prior to the reboot??; ie. are you using SysRq commands to the kernel bypassing any GUI/UI crash?  App crashes can be scanned for in `/var/crash/` (*may not have data for 3rd party apps, or snap & other non-deb package apps*) but you weren't specific as to app, nor app type (*where to look for clues will depend on the app & app type/package format which you didn't specify*).

Comment: Please add additional details, or clarifications to your question; comments are from *readers* who are asking questions to the *Original Poster* or a prior *commentator* and won't be used in the actual *answers* which will be to the initial question.  This is a Q&A site & not a forum don't forget (https://ubuntuforums.org/ being the address of Ubuntu Forums)